# question about download asset unity from unity bucket by addressable

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Let me ask, is there any way to delete a specific bundle file in the cache to update new assets on the unity bucket without using Caching.Clear Cache(); to delete all bundle files in cache, thanks!

I hope there is a solution to delete specific bundles before downloading assets from unity bucket

Comment: Using the `Addressables` package assumes that you don't need to know anything about concrete bundle. However, you can try to clear all dependencies using https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.6/api/UnityEngine.AddressableAssets.Addressables.html?q=updatecat#UnityEngine_AddressableAssets_Addressables_ClearDependencyCacheAsync_System_Object_

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.